# What is the difference between while and between, and what is the better choice in my case?

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, limit, between

I have a table that have hundreds of rows, and i want to get specific rows, I used the LIMIT and between id and id
In my application i have two text inputs, one is for START NUMBER and one is for END NUMBER, When i use the LIMIT i need to tell the user to make the right calculation to get the right start and end
So for example if i have a table of 3000 rows, and i want to select 100 rows above 2000 the query will be :

```
Select * from table LIMIT 2000,100
```

This will select 100 rows above 2000

The between method :

In the between method, i'm running a while function on all the table and i'm using IF statement to get the right id's here is what i'm doing :

```
Select * from table

$datastart = $_POST["datastart"];
$dataend = $_POST["dataend"];
$firstid = 0;
$lastid = 0;
$varcount6=1;

$sql = "select ID  from users_info";
$sqlread = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlread)){

    if($datastart==$varcount6){
        $firstid = $rowdirstid["ID"];
    }

    if($varcount6>=$dataend){
        $lastid = $rowdirstid["id1"];

        break;
    }

    $varcount6++;
}
```

So now i have the first id and the last id of the table, next i use another sql query :

```
Select * from table where id between $firstid and $lastid
```

Both worked

My question is: what should i use if i'm loading huge amount of data each time ?

Should i go with while ? or the LIMIT will make the job done ?

Comment: It's awful, you are doing a complete scan of the table every time. Why dont you use a normal index and where conditions? Example: 100 elements above 2000. SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID>=2000 ORDER BY ID LIMIT 100

Comment: @PerroVerd that's wrong, because the ID is not necessary the real row index. The code `Select * from table LIMIT 2000,100` is better than your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, you should never use PHP to get the data required, stick to doing that solely in SQL, as PHP is never needed.

The limit query you're using will not cut it for what you're trying to do, as it will not care what id's the entries has, so, if your id's are not 100% consecutive, you will not get the desired result.

You should use the between query you display at the bottom of your post.

But, since you haven't provided your full code I cannot say wether or not you sanitized that input, but that is always a good thing to keep in mind. It's preferable to use parameterized queries instead aswell.

Answer (score 0):

If your sure the ID are consecutive, use `SELECT * FROM t WHERE id BETWEEN a AND b ORDER BY ID ASC`
If you use LIMIT, the SQL Engine have to scan and order all the first results. 
(and index the `id` field)